# Rspec VCR and custom response

Tags: rspec, rspec2, vcr

Suppose, I have a request to google.com. I can record a cassette and use. But imagine situation when I need to test suite when google.com returns a 500 error code? How could it be done? I thought about manual change of the cassette file, but when I need to re-record all the cassettes I will need to change this cassette also and this does not suit my need 'cause I have lots of such cases

Or are there any alternatives to vcr which let do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need a response that is not easily recordable, VCR is not the right tool.  I recommend you use WebMock or the stubbing facilitates built-in to your HTTP library.  (Excon, Faraday and Typhoeus all have built-in stubbing APIs).

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help you:

http://railsware.com/blog/2013/10/03/custom-vcr-matchers-for-dealing-with-mutable-http-requests/

I am not sure because your question is vague. but hope it helps :)